# How to bring in multiple files from a directory individually into a Pandas dataframe and write out new file

Tags: pandas, function, dataframe

I have a couple hundred well plan txt files in a directory that I am trying to pull into a pandas dataframe and then output a new file.  My current code only works for one file at a time.  How can I write a function that will bring in each file one by one and output a new file for each?  This is what I've got so far.  Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import os

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/aschnel/Juypiter_Notebooks/Data/Dev_Survey_Arc/W1R1C01_v4_wp01.txt', skiprows=17, sep=" ")
df.columns=['Nan','MD', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'TVD', 'DX', 'DY', 'AZIM_TN', 'INCL', 'DLS', 'AZIM_GN']
df.drop('Nan', axis=1, inplace=True)

df.to_excel('WP1.xlsx', index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')
```

Comment: wrap it in a for loop?

Comment: Read about `glob` and `for loop`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) and `for` loop:

```
import glob

for filename in glob.glob("/path/*.txt"):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=17, sep=" ")
    df.columns=['Nan','MD', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'TVD', 'DX', 'DY', 'AZIM_TN', 'INCL', 'DLS', 'AZIM_GN']
    df.drop('Nan', axis=1, inplace=True)
    df.to_excel(filename + '.xlsx', index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')
```